# Retrieve Data Label Range/Formula from ChartObject

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart with data labels that pull from a range of cells. For some reason changing the cells will sometimes stop updating the labels. The hack: delete the labels and re-add them with the same formula reference.

I am already looping through the charts, then through each series. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
For Each myChart in ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    For Each mySeries in myChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection
           Dim dataLabelFormula as String
           'I'm missing this line here where I get that formula

           mySeries.DataLabels.Delete
           mySeries.ApplyDataLabels

           'Here, I set the formula for the data labels to the one I grabbed earlier (or would if I knew how)
           mySeries.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, dataLabelFormula, 0

           'I do some formatting stuff later like removing leader lines and values
    Next mySeries
Next myChart
```

As you see, I know how to SET the formula, just not how to retrieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it an actual typo in your code in Excel, because here you have `mySerieis.DataLabels` instead of `mySeries...`

Comment: No, just a typo in my question. I've fixed that now, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Daniel , did you try just forcing the chart to refresh using your loop?

Comment: @TheSilkCode, the issue is that the links... stagnate. Not sure how else to say it. If I refresh the data labels, they disappear instead of refreshing even though the formula is linked to the correct place. It's as if the data no longer exists. But if I delete them and use the same formula, they appear correctly. It's pretty perplexing.

Comment: Hi @Daniel , hmm it could be a broken reference issue- meaning something about the data source for the labels has been modified or changed (E.G.- a filename change, the data tab's name being changed, and inserting or deleting rows or columns on the data tab to name a few..) So couple questions to help narrow in on the root cause is 1) What changes are being done to the source file between the formulas working and not working? and 2) Could you paste an example of the label formulas you are using?